# Incorrect numbering of figures

Tags: numbering

Using the `scrartcl` class I have an incorrect numbering of Figures as illustrated in the example below. How can this problem be corrected? A MWE is listed below.

[image: Example of a PV system]

The code used for the example is listed below.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[1]

\section{Special case}

Figure \ref{fig:PV} shows an example of a  PV system installed on farmland.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width= 0.6\textwidth]{pv.png}
    \label{fig:PV}
    \caption{Green energy.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image is from Pixabay.]

Image by [Sebastian Ganso](https://pixabay.com/users/mrganso-607585/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=2742302) from [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=2742302)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `scrartcl`. The `\label` must come *after* `\caption`.

Comment: As campa says the label need to refer to what is giving the number, which is not the env nor `\includegraphics`, the number comes from `\caption` and this `\label` needs to come after it. Otherwise the label points to the latest _thing_ it can refer to in this case `\section{Special case}` which has the number `2`.

Comment: Placing the `\label` after the `\caption` solves the problem. The suggested answer "Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?"  is spot on, although, to find that post you must *already* now how to solve the problem!